# Correct way to update cell in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to give the ability to re-order rows in a table via the UI. The user selects a row, clicks Move Up or Move Down, and the row is moved. Moving the same row multiple times doesn't work correctly.

```
// This returns the data in currently displayed order whether 'current' or 'index' is passed as the modifier
var primaryKeyColData = self.DataTable.column(0, 'current').data();

// updatedFieldOrder is correct
for (const field of updatedFieldOrder)
{
    for (var index = 0; index < primaryKeyColData.length; index++)
    {
        if (primaryKeyColData[index] != field[0]) continue;

        // The issue is here. cell(index) returns based on the original order. 
        // I can't get column() to return data in this order nor get that data to update. 
        // Stepping into the source the original order data is in aoData
        self.DataTable.cell(index, 8).data(field[1]);
        self.DataTable.row(index).invalidate();

        break;
    }
}

self.DataTable.draw(false);
```

What am I missing? How do I find a single matching row based on data in one column, update the data in another column, re-draw and do this multiple times?

Thanks,
-Mont

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: The syntax you are using in `column(0, 'current')` does not look correct. That second parameter (the [selector modifier](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier)) has to be specified as follows:  `column(0, {order: 'current'} )`.

Comment: How are you selecting a row? Using the [Select](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/) extension, or some other way?

Comment: Does the [Row Re-Order](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/) extension meet your needs? (sorry for all the comments!).

Comment: There is an example anbout re-ordering in the [documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/events.html). Have a look... Because your code does not seem to be close... Making it hard to answer.

Comment: Thank you @andrewjames my foolish mistake with the parameter was the issue. As soon as I passed the 'index' parameter correctly everything worked. Also thanks for pointing out the row re-order extension I was now aware of it.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thanks for the reference to the documentation about the row re-order extension. It doesn't work for me in this instance but I am glad to know it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final working code to manually re-position a row.

```
var self = this;

// Get the data for the column by which rows can be uniquely identified.
// Data will be in the original order.
var rowIdColData = self.DataTable.column(self.RowIdCol, { order: 'index' }).data();

// updateFieldOrder is a two dimensional array. Each entry holds a value to identify
// a row in the first position and the value to be changed in the second position
for (const field of updatedFieldOrder)
{
    for (var index = 0; index < rowIdColData.length; index++)
    {
        if (rowIdColData[index] != field[self.RowIdCol]) continue;

        // Update the data in the desired column. ".cell()" references rows
        // in their original order.
        self.DataTable.cell(index, self.ColToBeChanged).data(field[1]);

        break;
    }
}

self.DataTable.draw(false); // Update table, do not re-paginate
```